# Distance Education Programs in Digital Forensics

Tags: forensics, career, academia

I am looking for a distance education program with the end product being a Masters of Science in Digital Forensics. I looked through the site and did not find any results, and was hoping since most people here are in the industry, someone might know a couple more.

 I only know UCF's [Msc in Digital Forensics](http://msdf.ucf.edu/), and even this one is partially online. I can't attend in residence, as I am an engineering during the day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boston University Looks like it has what you are looking for.
http://www.bu.edu/online/programs/certificate-programs/digital-forensics.html

Also Champlain College has a program as well. 
http://www.champlain.edu/Graduate-Studies/Programs/Master-of-Science-in-Digital-Forensic-Management.html